# Dialog error in android

Tags: android, dialog

I am not able to understand why I'm getting error saying

> Dialog cannot be resolved to a type

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;


  public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment 
    {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog( Bundle savedInstanceState )
        {
            return new AlertDialog.Builder( getActivity() ).setTitle( R.string.date_picker_title )
                                                 .setPositiveButton( android.R.string.ok, null )
                                                 .create(); 
        }
```

Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to import `android.app.Dialog`.

If you look at [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.html), `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` extends `android.app.Dialog`.

In Android Studio, you can just click on the item that doesn't compile, and click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in order to add the necessary import. If there are multiple possibilities, it will give you a list to choose from.

```
import android.app.Dialog; //added
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;


public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .create();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!
I'm learning from some book and they only mentioned to import support.v4.app.DialogFragment . and for some reason auto-complete imports didn't work ..